# How to identify where the memory leak is?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm trying to rid my code of memory leaks but can't quite narrow down exactly where the leak is coming from.

```
void insertHead(T value){
        if(!duplicateCheck(value)){
            length++;
            if(head == NULL){
                head = new Node(value);
            }else{
                Node *temp = head;
                head = new Node(value);
                head->next = temp;
            }
        }
  }

void insertTail(T value){
        if(!duplicateCheck(value)){
            // create the node
            if(head == NULL){// insert at the insertHead
                insertHead(value); //head = newNode;
            }else{// Iterators through the linked list until a null is found
                length++;
                Node *fakeIterator = head; // once found sets the null val to newNode
                while(fakeIterator->next != NULL){
                    fakeIterator = fakeIterator->next;
                }
                fakeIterator->next = new Node(value);
            }
        }
  }

void insertAfter(T value, T insertionNode){ // seg faulting because it cant find the object oadd after
        if(!duplicateCheck(value)){
            Node *fakeIterator = head;
            while (fakeIterator != NULL) {
                    if (fakeIterator->value == insertionNode) {
                            Node *newNode = new Node(value);
                            newNode->next = fakeIterator->next;
                            fakeIterator->next = newNode;
                            length++;
                            break;
                    }
                    fakeIterator = fakeIterator->next;
            }
        }
  }

void clear(){
        Node *fakeIterator = head;
        while(fakeIterator!=NULL){
            delete head;
            fakeIterator = fakeIterator->next;
            head = fakeIterator;
        }
        head = NULL;
        length = 0;
  }
```

The Clear function is called in the deconstructor and main's purpose to delete each node. I used valgrind and it said there is memory lost in all of the insert methods but again im just not sure where. I can post the valgrind output if need be

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: It's worth noting you `delete` your `fakeIterator` in `clear()` and then go ahead and use that deleted object. That's undefined behaviour, a use-after-free bug. Capture `fakeIterator->next` *before* you delete.

Comment: Strongly consider using `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique()` instead of raw pointers with `new` and `delete`.

Comment: `Clear()` has undefined behaviour if `head` is not `NULL`.    The first thing it does is `delete head`, which invalidates `fakeIterator`, so the access of `fakeIerator->next` in the assignment `fakeIterator = fakeIterator->next` gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @tadman @Peter Would this be better? I guess I need to read up more on LinkedLists and memory management in general ```while(fakeIterator!=NULL){
   fakeIterator = fakeIterator->next;
   delete head;
   head = fakeIterator;
  }
```

Comment: Try and use `nullptr` in C++, but yes, that's more of the right idea. `fakeIterator` is a terrible name though. It's not fake. It's a real iterator.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you've initialized the `next` field to null in `Node` constructor.

In your `insertTail` function, your loop condition involves pointer access, which is illegal if the pointer is null. Also, as @tadman mentioned, you're accessing a deleted element. (Note that while accessing, your `head` and `fakeptr` point to the same element. They must point to consecutive elements if you want to delete them)

Generally, compiling with the `-g` flag (in case of g++ or clang++) and then running valgrind would output the exact line numbers where your memory leak is taking place.

You could also use both gdb and valgrind together. Please refer [this link](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html) for more info.

Comment: Your assumption is correct with next being set to null in the constructor.
I do check if the head is null before accessing the next node in the loop. Since fakeptr is set to head doesn't that prevent the error?